# Can I install Ubuntu on a Samsung Wave 2 S8530 phone that is running Bada OS?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I'm using Bada OS Version 1.2 on my Samsung Wave 2 S8530.

My phone's hardware is:
⠀• 1GHz processor
⠀• 512MB RAM
⠀• 2GB Internal memory
⠀• Hummingbird chipset
⠀• 73MB GPU memory

I have a 32GB UHS 1 Class 10 microSD card. Please tell me can I install Ubuntu on my phone?

Answer (score 1):

Supported phones: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices

You are unable to install Ubuntu Touch on your phone.